# Using the Distance formula to adjust coordinates

Tags: r, function, loops, while-loop

I have a chart with a bunch of Polar Chart images pasted on top of it given some x and y coordinates. However, some of those charts overlap. I need to create a way to space each chart by a distance of 15, but minimizing how much x and y change.

So if a point has a distance of 13 from another point, the point that is furthest from my origin (50,50) moves by a distance of 2 to make sure the new distance between points is 15. By distance, I mean the distance between points using the distance formula. *The origin is (50,50) because that is the center of my new image.*

**Function**

I am thinking of creating a `check.x` and a `check.y` function with:

- arguments for the distance between the points
- their distance from the (50,50) origin (either as a rank i.e. 1 to k such that k is the further point from the origin or the actual distance)
- old x_coordinate & y_coordinate of our point we are moving
- x_coordinate & y_coordinate of our point we are testing against

The function would test a given point against a test point. If the given point is further from the origin, then move it, otherwise do nothing. If the given point is furthest from the origin and the distance between the given point and test point is less than 15, then move the given point by a distance of 15. Otherwise, do nothing.

I have a rough draft of it below, but I am having trouble in terms of how to write the arguments and what to return. Observe:

```
 ## Creates new x coordinate given points
check.x<-function(x,rank1,rank2, distance,y_cor.1,x_cor.2,y_cor.2){
  origin.x=x_cor.2
  origin.y=y_cor.2
  newish.x=x-x_cor.2
  newish.y=y_cor.1-y_cor.2
  theta=atan2(newish.y,newish.x)
  if(rank1>rank2){##adjust x
    if(distance<15&distance!=0){
      new.x<-cos(theta)*15+50
    }else{}
  }else{}
  return(new.x)
}

## Creates new y coordinate given points
check_y<-function(y,rank1,rank2, distance,x_cor.1,x_cor.2,y_cor.2){
  origin.x=x_cor.2
  origin.y=y_cor.2
  newish.x=x_cor.1-x_cor.2
  newish.y=y-y_cor.2
  theta=atan2(newish.y,newish.x)
  if(rank1>rank2){##adjust x
    if(distance<15&distance!=0){
      new.y<-sin(theta)*15+50
    }else{}
  }else{}
  return(new.y)
}
```

**Loop**

When I run this, I believe I should put it into a `while loop` for `distance<15`. However, when I `join` on my dataframe to itself it can be done once. Then I copmute the `check.` But then I need to re-check the distance and thus join on the dataframe again with the new points. How do I correct for this to reduce the number of joins and make it such that it overwrites the new point? I have coded as much as I can, but cannot think of the next step further, but provided comments as steps to follow for how I think it should go. Each `##` indicates a new step

```
## Coordinate DataFrame
coordf<-data.frame(df$Id,df$GroupId,df$x_coordinate,df$y_coordinate)
coordf<-coordf[!duplicated(coordf$df.Id),]
colnames(coordf)<-c('Id','Group','x_coordinate','y_coordinate')
coordf$DistOrigin<-sqrt((coordf$x_coordinate-50)^2+(coordf$y_coordinate-50)^2)
## Orders/Ranks position based on distance to origin
coordf$rank<-ave(coordf$DistOrigin,
               factor(paste(coordf$Group)),
               FUN=rank)
point_df<-coordf%>% mutate(k=1)       ## dummy column
point_df<-point_df%>%                  ## Distance between each points
  full_join(point_df,by='k')%>%
  mutate(dist=sqrt((x_coordinate.x-x_coordinate.y)^2+(y_coordinate.x-y_coordinate.y)^2))%>%
  select(-k)
## Removes the points that are the same, i.e. x1=x2 and y1=y2 and within same group
point_df<-point_df[(point_df$Group.x==point_df$Group.y),]
point_df<-point_df[(point_df$dist!=0),]
## Loop ... I have also never written a while loop before in R
## This is where I get lost due to the complexity
while (distance <15){
  ## Run check.x and check.y
  ## Take the return values and attach them in a new column
  ## Recheck the distance
  ## Re-rank the points in response to the (50,50) origin
}
```

** Data **

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
GroupId<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
Id<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
x_coordinate<-c(32,35,56,53,33,32,38,59)
y_coordinate<-c(63,58,56,49,40,33,32,51)
df<-data.frame(Id,GroupId,x_coordinate,y_coordinate)
```

Comment: You could have a grid of valid x,y points and have each of your current points move to one of the grid points. Googling "snap to grid algorithms" should turn up some helpful links.